# Set headers during laravel dusk testing

Tags: laravel, automated-tests, laravel-dusk

I am testing locales for my current project. Unfortunaltey, I am unable to pass headers during a dusk browser tests. Tried searching a whole lot but coundn't find a solution. Please suggest.

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
    // need to pass headers here. e.g. mysite-locale = en-us then expect the cookie value to be 'en-us'
    $browser->visit(config('app.url'));
    $this->assertEquals($browser->plainCookie('mysite-locale'), 'en-ca');
});
```

In one of our services, the languages is set based on `Accept-Language` ... `$this->request->header('Accept-Language')`. Hence the need to set headers during dusk tests.

Comment: something like this won't be test with end-to-end testing it is better using noraml unit testing

Comment: @Joseph Would you please suggest what other `normal unit testing` to use?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests

Comment: I wanna go through E2E testing. Hence, laravel dusk. Feature/Unit tests are not enough at the moment.